# `expl3` create "function" that returns a bool and passing to `\bool_if`

Tags: conditionals, expl3

I am trying to understand how to abstract `expl3` code into "functions".

So far, I have a working macro to detect whether a token is a capital letter:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\iscapital{m} {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} {\tl_upper_case:n { #1 }} { T }{ F }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

a: \iscapital{a}
A: \iscapital{A}
```

I try to abstract this in two ways:

Method 1:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\iscapital{m} {
    \bool_if:nTF { \__iscapital:n {#1} }{ T }{ F }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iscapital:n {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} {\tl_upper_case:n { #1 }} {\c_true_bool}{\c_false_bool}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and Method 2:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\iscapital{m} {
    \bool_if:nTF { \__iscapital:n {#1} }{ T }{ F }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iscapital:n {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_upper_case:n { #1 } }

    \str_if_eq:eeTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl { \c_true_bool }{ \c_false_bool }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Method 1 works but Method 2 errors. Why is this? And, is there a way to make a "function" like Method 2 that does a bunch of work before evaluating to `\c_*_bool`?

Comment: The first argument of `\bool_if:nTF` has to be fully expandable until it expands to `\c_true_bool` or `\c_false_bool`, so you can't assign values to variables. (That's also the reason why tests such as `\tl_if_in:nnTF` don't have a `_p` variant.)

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, do the unexpandable stuff first and then use either the first or the second following group (e.g., `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \iscapital:n #1 { TF } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_upper_case:n { #1 } } \str_if_eq:eeTF \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: } }`).

Comment: What's the reason for preferring method 2 if method 1 works?

Comment: @egreg I am trying to understand how to program in `expl3`, not necessarily solve the `iscapital` problem.

Comment: @JasonSiefken OK, so look at my answer to see how to properly define conditional structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want fully expandable functions, so no `\tl_set:Nn`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\iscapitalTF}{mmm}
 {
  \siefken_if_capital:eTF { \tl_head:n { #1 } } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \siefken_if_capital:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_uppercase:n { #1 } } { #1 }
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \siefken_if_capital:n { e } { p,T,F,TF }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

a: \iscapitalTF{a}{T}{F}

A: \iscapitalTF{A}{T}{F}

abc: \iscapitalTF{abc}{T}{F}

Abc: \iscapitalTF{Abc}{T}{F}

\end{document}
```

[image]